# Django properly add foreign key from newly created model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create a foreign key in my Project Model. The foreign key is from a newly created model.

```
class Status:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Project(models.Model):
    projectID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    projectBrief = models.TextField(default="")
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Getting the following error

```
line 939, in __init__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: ForeignKey(<class 'projects.models.Status'>) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'
```

PS: I have been working on JSP from a long (I know pretty bad, where I can just add remove db fields without issue). Recently started learning Django. So please guide accordingly. Thanks.

I am using the following commands

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

I am not able to successfully migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Really sorry for my overlook. Thanks to ChatGPT.
I am not inheriting from models.Model

correct code should be

```
from django.db import models

class Status(models.Model):  # Make sure to inherit from models.Model
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Project(models.Model):
projectID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
projectBrief = models.TextField(default="")
status = models.ForeignKey(Status, blank=True, null=True, 
on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).